# C# - Most OOP way to pass data between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, oop

Let's say I have a thread that waits for a user to click a button before advancing:

```
System.Threading.AutoResetEvent dialoguePause = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);

public void AskQuestion()
{
  /* buttons containing choices created here */

  dialoguePause.WaitOne();

  /*Code that handles choice here */
}

public void Choice_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dialoguePause.Set();
}
```

How can I pass data from the thread Choice_Clicked is on to AskQuestion without relying on class variables? The best I can do is this:

```
System.Threading.AutoResetEvent dialoguePause = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
string mostRecentChoice;


public void AskQuestion()
{
  /* buttons containing choices created here */

  dialoguePause.WaitOne();

  MessageBox.Show("You chose " + mostRecentChoice + ".");
}

public void Choice_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  mostRecentChoice = (sender as Button).Content.ToString(); //Ugly!
  dialoguePause.Set();
}
```

Comment: Don't use threads, use the Task Async Pattern (async/await). Only start new threads for long-running, CPU-bound operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this:

- Use a property in a Singleton or Monostate. There is always one instance of such property, so regardless which thread writes, and which reads, the will share it, as long as they are in one Application Domain.
- Use messaging
- If you are in same class, use field or property (look out for cross-threads!)
- ...

What I am trying to say, it depends on the application. I have no clue if this is WinForm, WPF or Web ...